# Interfacing haskell with c

Tags: haskell, ffi

I've been thinking that it would be nice to create midori plugins with haskell, but it seems to be nigh impossible. The problem lies with exporting haskell functions through ffi, as the ghc compiler makes use of a massive amount of -u switches.

tHas anyone seen haskell been used in a similar context, without having to replace gcc for ghc? If so, how did it work out and what hoops did they go through?

Edit: Some examples were requested, so here:

export.hs

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
module Export where
import Foreign.C
import Foreign.C.Types

foo :: IO Int
foo = return 2

foreign export ccall foo :: IO Int
```

test.c (ifdefs snipped)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "HsFFI.h"
#include "export_stub.h"

extern void __stginit_Export(void);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    hs_init(&argc, &argv);
    hs_add_root(__stginit_Export);
    i = foo();
    printf("%d\n", i);
    hs_exit();
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling with `ghc --make -no-hs-main export.hs test.c` creates an a.out
executable which works. The ghc uses the following command for linking:

`collect2 --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_i386 --hash-style=both -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -o a.out -z relro -u ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Izh_static_info -u ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Czh_static_info -u ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Fzh_static_info -u ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Dzh_static_info -u base_GHCziPtr_Ptr_static_info -u base_GHCziWord_Wzh_static_info -u base_GHCziInt_I8zh_static_info -u base_GHCziInt_I16zh_static_info -u base_GHCziInt_I32zh_static_info -u base_GHCziInt_I64zh_static_info -u base_GHCziWord_W8zh_static_info -u base_GHCziWord_W16zh_static_info -u base_GHCziWord_W32zh_static_info -u base_GHCziWord_W64zh_static_info -u base_GHCziStable_StablePtr_static_info -u ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Izh_con_info -u ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Czh_con_info -u ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Fzh_con_info -u ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Dzh_con_info -u base_GHCziPtr_Ptr_con_info -u base_GHCziPtr_FunPtr_con_info -u base_GHCziStable_StablePtr_con_info -u ghczmprim_GHCziBool_False_closure -u ghczmprim_GHCziBool_True_closure -u base_GHCziPack_unpackCString_closure -u base_GHCziIOziException_stackOverflow_closure -u base_GHCziIOziException_heapOverflow_closure -u base_ControlziExceptionziBase_nonTermination_closure -u base_GHCziIOziException_blockedIndefinitelyOnMVar_closure -u base_GHCziIOziException_blockedIndefinitelyOnSTM_closure -u base_ControlziExceptionziBase_nestedAtomically_closure -u base_GHCziWeak_runFinalizzerBatch_closure -u base_GHCziTopHandler_runIO_closure -u base_GHCziTopHandler_runNonIO_closure -u base_GHCziConc_ensureIOManagerIsRunning_closure -u base_GHCziConc_runSparks_closure -u base_GHCziConc_runHandlers_closure /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../lib/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../lib/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/ghc-6.12.1/base-4.2.0.0 -L/usr/lib/ghc-6.12.1/integer-gmp-0.2.0.0 -L/usr/lib/ghc-6.12.1/ghc-prim-0.2.0.0 -L/usr/lib/ghc-6.12.1 -L/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3 -L/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3 -L/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../lib -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../..  -L/usr/lib/i486-linux-gnu export.o export_stub.o test.o -lHSbase-4.2.0.0 -lHSinteger-gmp-0.2.0.0 -lgmp -lHSghc-prim-0.2.0.0 -lHSrts -lm -lffi -lrt -ldl -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../lib/crtn.o`

Removing the `-u` switches (leaving just -l, -L and some extra flags) from
the previous command doesn't compile and returns (and some 50 or so more
lines)

```
/usr/lib/ghc-6.12.1/libHSrts.a(RtsAPI.o): In function `rts_mkFunPtr':
(.text+0x5a9): undefined reference to `base_GHCziPtr_FunPtr_con_info'
/usr/lib/ghc-6.12.1/libHSrts.a(RtsAPI.o): In function `rts_mkString':
(.text+0x60f): undefined reference to `base_GHCziPack_unpackCString_closure'
```

Comment: This is probably the related part of the manual: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/ffi-ghc.html
See 8.2.1.2 in particular. You can make a library written in Haskell and callable from C code. Then you have only to write some glue code in C to turn in into a plugin or whatever. But I didn't do it myself, please wait for more experienced users of "foreign export" to answer.

Comment: @Jetxee, are you aware that writing an answer as a comment forbids the OP to accept it? :)

Comment: Yes you are right, but when trying to link those objects, will cause undefined errors, which can be fixed with -u switches, but there are a lot of them, and I _think_ they might change from program to program

Comment: @Kos OK, I posted it as an answer :) @Masse Could you please post a minimal example to compile, how exactly you are trying to build it and what are the errors. Then someone may try to solve your particular problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem.

I'm using the following files:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lib_stub.h"
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    puts("foo");
    printf("%d\n", hsfun(5));
    return 0;
}
```

lib.hs

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
module Test where
import Foreign.C.Types

hsfun :: CInt -> IO CInt
hsfun x = do
  putStrLn "Hello from haskell"
  return (42 * x)

foreign export ccall hsfun :: CInt -> IO CInt
```

module_init.c

```
#include <HsFFI.h>
extern void __stginit_Test(void);

static void library_init(void) __attribute__((constructor));
static void library_init(void)
{
    static char *argv[] = { "libtest.so", 0 }, **argv_ = argv;
    static int argc = 1;

    hs_init(&argc, &argv_);
    hs_add_root(__stginit_Test);
}

static void library_exit(void) __attribute__((destructor));
static void library_exit(void)
{
    hs_exit();
}
```

I'm compiling the library with `ghc --make -shared -dynamic -fPIC -o
libtest.so lib.hs module_init.c -lHSrts-ghc6.12.1
-optl-Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/ghc-6.12.1/ -L/usr/lib/ghc-6.12.1` and the
executable with `gcc -c main.c -I/usr/lib/ghc-6.12.1/include -L. -ltest
-Wl,-rpath=$PWD`

The important part is making the library shared and having the rts library
linked also which doesn't come default. The rpath makes it so that it can
be ran without LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

http://weblog.haskell.cz/pivnik/building-a-shared-library-in-haskell/

http://www.well-typed.com/blog/30

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the related part of the manual:

[8.2. Using the FFI with GHC](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/ffi-ghc.html)

See 8.2.1.2 in particular. You can make a library written in Haskell and callable from C code. Then you have only to write some glue code in C to turn in into a plugin or whatever. But I didn't do it myself, please wait for more experienced users of `foreign export` to answer.